# Loading/removing dynamically buffers with Vulkan

Tags: multithreading, opengl, buffer, vulkan

I switched to Vulkan from OpenGL to use multi-threading improvements.

In OpenGL, I was able to load dynamically object to the scene (buffer, textures, etc) while rendering by using a waiting system. I was loading all app-side stuffs in a thread, then when it was ready, just before a frame render in the main thread, I was sending everything into the video memory. That was fine.

With Vulkan, I know I can call some functions between threads without provoking the well known segfault from OpenGL. But, this doesn't works with vkQueueSubmit(). I already know, I tried the naive way. To me, it seems logical you can't bother a queue from multiple threads.

I came with some ideas, but I don't know which one is good or bad.

First, I would go the OpenGL way, I will prepare everything I can from the CPU/App side, then just before render a frame, I will submit buffers (with transfer queue) to the video memory. But I feel there is no a real improvement from OpenGL way...

Second, I will try to use the synchronization mechanism to be able to send buffers in a thread and render from an other. But I keep reading there is a lot of way to slow down everything by causing irrelevant locks or by using incorrectly semaphores and fences.

So my question, is basically what path to pick to solve this problem ? How can I load a buffer dynamically from an other thread while the main thread is rendering without making too much pain to performances ? How Vulkan can help ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stream resources for immediate use (i.e. the main render cannot proceed without them), then you're pretty much going to either block the main thread waiting, or have it spin doing something visually interesting (e.g. an animated loading screen) waiting for the resources to load.

If you want to stream resources while the app is doing real rendering then the main trick here is to load resources asynchronously in the background and only switch to using those resources in the main thread once they are already loaded. If the main thread ever ends up actually blocked on a semaphore then you've probably already started dropping frames, so your "engine" design needs to ensure that never happens. A lot of game use simple low-detail proxy objects as stand-in versions while the high-detail version is loading in the background.

None of this is particularly related to the graphics API - both GL and Vulkan need the same macro-scale behavior. Vulkan API features don't particularly help because the major bottlenecks which cause problems here are storage/network/CPU which have nothing to do with the graphics part of the problem.

Comment: OpenGL keeps everything relatively simple and the driver will pause the main thread if it needs to (it probably doesn't, but it will pause the GPU command stream instead). I am not familiar with Vulkan but is it really not possible to place synchronization points in the command stream so that the GPU knows to wait for a certain transfer to complete before continuing?

Comment: For CPU-to-GPU synchronization, there is limited support (you can signal timeline semaphores from the CPU).

For GPU-to-GPU transfer operations, e.g. transfer via a staging buffer, you get the full spectrum of options (sems, fences, pipeline barriers).

Comment: Bulk transfer is slow and you are likely to drop frames if pipelining too aggressively. It's much better to design the system entirely client-side. The main render thread should never use a resource until it knows it's already available, at which point you don't need API-side sync primitives.

Comment: Yes, I know everything you talk about, and as I said, I already done this in OpenGL without any problem. But, I would like to use Vulkan logics to load things across multiple threads, that all. Should I go like OpenGL, basically doing everything (the minimal possible calls to API) in main thread or use semaphores/fences to sort queue works between threads ?

Comment: I still don't understand where your "between threads" part is coming from in terms of API sem/fence concerns. If you are pipelining so that thread A loads a resource,  and uses CPU-side (non-API) sync to ensure thread B will never use the resource until thread A is done, then there is no real need for API synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to trust threads !

In the first place it seems to work, I get a lot of :

```
[MESSAGE:Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-MultipleThreads ] Object 0: handle = 0x56414228bad8, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; | MessageID = 0x141cb623 | THREADING ERROR : vkQueueSubmit(): object of type VkQueue is simultaneously used in thread 0x7f6b977fe640 and thread 0x7f6bc2bcb740]
```

But it works !

So, the basic idea is to have a thread for loading objects while the engine is drawing. This thread takes care of creating the UBO for the location of the object, then when the geometry is loaded from RAM, it creates the VBO and IBO (I left material with image/UBO on hold for now), then creates the graphics pipeline (with layout, descriptor layout, shaders compiled with GLSLang on the fly) (The next idea is to reuse pipeline for similar needs) and finallly sets a flag to say the object is ready to use. In the other hand, I have my main thread rendering and takes new objects when they shows up ready.

I think it works because I have a gentle video card (GTX 1070) with multiple queues setup, I had one for graphics and an other one for transfer setup.

I'm pretty sure, this will crash or goes poorly with a GPU with a single queue, and this should be why the validation layers tolds me these messages.

Comment: The usual approach is to have a single thread submitting to the queues, submitting command buffers that have been built by other threads. 

If you want async loading to run in the background and expect processing contention with the main render thread, you can set a loading queue to have lower priority than the main rendering queue which should mean it gets preempted if needed. This does need the platform to have multiple queues though.